# RequireJS inconsistent error with async and google maps api when using identity services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-identity, requirejs, amd

I'm working on a .NET 5 based MVC app.  I wanted to switch it to TypeScript and modularize the code.  The best way I found to do this is to build everything as AMD packages and use RequireJS for loading.  At first glance things seem to work OK but then I started seeing errors on some pages.  Any time there is an error I can do a CTRL-F5 and the page loads correctly without any error.  When the error occurs, it is near instantaneous.  It is not happening after 7 seconds (the default, I believe) so the "timeout" message appears to be false.

The most common error being seen is this one:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{REMOVED_API_KEY}}_unnormalized2,jquery
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
    at makeError (require.min.js:1)
    at R (require.min.js:1)
    at require.min.js:1
```

I'm not sure if it is just the error reporting format, but notice that there is extra text being added after the API key.

Another errors that happens at times is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializePage' of undefined
    at require-config.js:48
    at Object.execCb (require.min.js:1)
    at e.check (require.min.js:1)
    at e.<anonymous> (require.min.js:1)
    at require.min.js:1
    at require.min.js:1
    at each (require.min.js:1)
    at emit (require.min.js:1)
    at e.check (require.min.js:1)
    at enable (require.min.js:1)
```

"`initializePage`" is a function that is defined and usually works fine.  The background information below will show how it is setup.

A third error that can appear at times:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return t.hljs}
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    at makeError (require.min.js:1)
    at T (require.min.js:1)
    at require.min.js:1
```

I can't find anything in the project with "`return t.hljs`", so I guess this has to be generated code.

Now comes the strangest part.  This site uses Identity Management to authenticate users.  If the user is not logged in, no errors are occurring.

For background, first, here is the config I'm using for RequireJS:

```
function requireConfig(mapsApiKey) {
    var mapsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + mapsApiKey;
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '/js',
        paths: {
            'async': '../lib/requirejs-plugins/async.min',
            'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery.min',
            'bootstrap': '../lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min',
            'datatables.net': '../lib/datatables.net/jquery.dataTables.min',
            'datatables.net-bs4': '../lib/datatables.net-bs4/dataTables.bootstrap4.min',
            'datatables.net-responsive': '../lib/datatables.net-responsive/dataTables.responsive.min',
            'datatables.net-responsive-bs4': '../lib/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/responsive.bootstrap4.min',
            'jquery-validation': '../lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min',
            'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': '../lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min',
            'select2': '../lib/select2/js/select2.min'
        },
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: 'jquery'
            },
            'bootstrap': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'Bootstrap'
            },
            'datatables.net-bs4': {
                deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'datatables.net']
            },
            'datatables.net-responsive-bs4': {
                deps: ['datatables.net-bs4', 'datatables.net-responsive']
            },
            'jquery.validate': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'jquery.validate.unobtrusive': {
                deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-validation']
            },
            'select2': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
    });

    define('gmaps', ['async!' + mapsUrl], function () { return window.google.maps; });
}

function requireSite() {
    require(['site'], function (site) {
        site.initializePage();
    });
}
```

Next, here is my "`libman.json`" file so you can see what versions of various libraries are in use:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "jquery@3.5.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery/"
    },
    {
      "library": "twitter-bootstrap@4.6.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/twitter-bootstrap/"
    },
    {
      "library": "select2@4.0.13",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/select2/"
    },
    {
      "library": "font-awesome@5.15.2",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/"
    },
    {
      "library": "datatables.net@1.10.23",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/datatables.net/"
    },
    {
      "library": "datatables.net-responsive@2.2.7",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/datatables.net-responsive/"
    },
    {
      "library": "datatables.net-responsive-bs4@2.2.7",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/"
    },
    {
      "library": "datatables.net-bs4@1.10.23",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/datatables.net-bs4/"
    },
    {
      "library": "jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.11",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/"
    },
    {
      "library": "jquery-validate@1.19.2",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery-validate/"
    },
    {
      "library": "require.js@2.3.6",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/require.js/"
    },
    {
      "library": "requirejs-plugins@1.0.3",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/requirejs-plugins/",
      "files": [
        "async.min.js",
        "async.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the identity setup section from `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        var googleAuthNSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    });
```

I've been searching through various resources for over a week and although I see lots of related messages to the errors I'm seeing, none appear to be the exact pattern and none of the recommended remedies of worked.  Hopefully someone out there has an idea of what interaction is going on here or can suggest an alternate pattern to get this all working.

*Edit with information requested by Damian*

On pages with the 'initializePage' error, only the require.js script and the script with the require setup is loading.  No resources defined to require.js (including the site.js file) are being loaded and there is no attempt to load them.

CTRL-F5, and the page comes up just fine.

On pages getting the "Mismatched anonymous" error with "return t.hljs", all of the required scripts (site, jquery, bootstrap, and google-maps) are loading in under 3 ms.

CTRL-F5 fixes these pages as well.

It took a while but I finally triggered a page that had the module timeout error with google maps.  On that one, the require.js and require setup scripts loaded, followed by the site.js and the async module for require.  Noe of the other scripts (mentioned above) were loaded and there were no callouts to load them.

Comment: Can you check the network panel in the browser developer tools and check whether the Google maps javascript file is loading?

Comment: Damian, added details to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a script race. If RequireJS is loaded before a script then you have an error because, the script tries loads itself via RequireJS

Comment: The only scripts being manually loaded are require.js and the script which handles top-level loads invoking require() functions.  I had tried to resolve all possible hidden dependencies with the "shim" definitions.  I'll try going back through library by library to see if I accidently created a circular reference, but I have my doubts there being that a CTRL-F5 will usually cause a good load and execute.